# Loading form from URL in Bootstrap 3 (Django)

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-forms

I have a form in a url.

I want to load it in an existing page.

I'm following this tutorial https://www.abidibo.net/blog/2014/05/26/how-implement-modal-popup-django-forms-bootstrap/

This is the form template

```
{% load i18n widget_tweaks %}
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <form action="{% url 'flag_post' %}" method="post" id="flag-form" class="form">{% csrf_token %}
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Report Post</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                {{ form.media }}
                {% render_field form.reason class="form-control" %}
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save changes" />
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </form>
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
<script>
    var form_options = { target: '#modal', success: function(response) {} };
    $('#flag-form').ajaxForm(form_options);
</script>
```

This is my link that is supposed to load the form

```
<a class="fa fa-pencil" data-toggle="modal" href="{% url 'flag_post' node.uid %}" data-target="#modal" title="edit item" data-tooltip></a> |
```

I have the following script tag embedded

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

When I call the url directly the form is displayed, but when I try clicking the button form is not loaded.

What is wrong with my code?

Is this the right way to load a form from an external URL?

Comment: where is #model id in your code ? is this complete code for your model ?

Comment: This is complete code

Comment: in your link your **data-target="#modal"** can you please tell where is this id modal this target is referring to. you need to enclose your code within another **div** with **id= "modal"**

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't include that. Now it's working once I add to code

Comment: happy to help mate :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have a modal placeholder.

Now I have

```
<a href="{% url 'flag_post' node.uid %}" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Report</a>
```

Then at the bottom of the page

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<!-- Content will be loaded here from "remote.php" file -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And it works! No JS and no other problems.

Now all I need to do is ajaxify my form submission.

Thanks @Sumeet Kumar

This link helped me

https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=modal-with-remote-url